# I have a column of URLs, but i am only able to extract data for one of the URL

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

"With assistance, I was able to extract a list of weblinks which are sorted according to years (from 1919-2019). Based on these weblinks, i would like to extract table data"

"I am able to get the URLS from 1919-2019. However, i would need to get additional links from each of the year-links"

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}


#start of code
mainurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/"
def getAndParseURL(mainurl):
   result = requests.get(mainurl)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
   datatable = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
   return datatable

datatable = getAndParseURL(mainurl)

#go through the content and grab the URLs
links = []
for link in datatable:
    if 'Year' in link['href']:
        url = link['href']
        links.append(mainurl + url)


#check if links are in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['url'])

df.head(10)


#save the dataframe

yearlinks = df.to_csv('C:/Users/123/aviationsafetyyearlinks.csv')

#obtained list of URLs.

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/123/aviationsafetyyearlinks.csv')

ankers = df.url
for anker in ankers:
    result = requests.get(anker, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
    datatable2 = soup.find_all('a', href = True)

    print(datatable2)


links = []
for link in datatable2:
    if "id=" in link['href']:
        url = link['href']
        links.append(mainurl + url)

#check if links are in dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['addurl'])

print(df2)
```

"Based on the code, i am only able to get the individual links for year 2019, i am not sure why but datatable2 shows all of the HTML content from 1919 - 2019 with each additional link" "Appreciate any form of help and many thanks in advance!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating datatable2 afresh each time in loop so only retain last values from loop. You want to create outside and append to it in loop. I make use of css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selectors and list comprehensions to do the url filtering.

You could do a little variable/function renaming, re-use connection with `Session` and tidy away a few lines of code. 
Change one of the `href` checks to attribute value contains `database/record`, so as to get only applicable links, and alter the append prefix to the end urls.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
main_url = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/"

def get_and_parse_url(main_url):
    result = s.get(main_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
    data_table = [main_url + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*=Year]')]
    return data_table

with requests.Session() as s:
    data_table = get_and_parse_url(main_url)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_table, columns=['url'])
    datatable2 = [] #create outside so can append to it

    for anker in df.url:
        result = s.get(anker, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
        datatable2.append(['https://aviation-safety.net' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*="database/record"]')])

 #flatten list of lists
datatable2 = [i for sublist in datatable2 for i in sublist]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(datatable2 , columns=['add_url'])
print(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr! This seems to be able to extract the links However, the links are not accessible <https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.ph...>, is there something I am not doing right?

Comment: The links are fine. You just need to loop df2.add_url  and print out.